# How to select rows within some date range

Tags: mysql

I want to select rows that falls between some date range, I tried the following query but it didn't work.

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%2011-%c-%e') BETWEEN '2011-11-28' AND '2011-12-5'
```

It doesn't seem like the BETWEEN keyword works on date. Please how do I get the results? Thanks

Comment: what is the data type for date_col?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT * FROM tbl WHERE DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN '2011-11-28' AND '2011-12-5'
```

Answer (score 9):

You don't need to use `DATE_FORMAT` if you want to compare dates.

```
SELECT * 
FROM tbl 
WHERE DATE(date_col) BETWEEN '2011-11-28' AND '2011-12-05'
```

Your code compares strings, assuming you use `DATE_FORMAT(date_col, '%Y-%c-%e')`